# "Want a C# Job?" No, actually

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I keep getting this advertisement (or one like it):

[image: Jorbs]

I've got nothing against its existence or what it's trying to do, except for one...tiny...detail:

## I don't want a [C#] job, I want a [Unity3d] job

If I look at my `/jobs` settings I have this as my (last, current, and only saved search):

```
[unity3d] game developer jobs excluding [ruby-on-rails] [python] in United States
```

And I was currently browsing the [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) questions list.

So why for the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)?

There does not appear to be anyway to tell the advertisement "no" or in any way adjust what it's showing me. At best, I can go to each company and say "dismiss this company," which isn't actually helpful.

Comment: could be predictive because you was looking at the unity3d tag. C# is in Unity and a lot of unity3d questions do get tagged as c# aswell

Comment: Oh certainly @Memor-X but that's like saying "here are some rectangles" when doing a search for squares. Afterall, squares *are* rectangles...

Comment: One time on another Q&A board they started these types of advertisements, and apparently 'SQL Server' was communicated as separate words, so these ads invited me to apply for all sorts of wonderful waiter positions at places like Applebees, Buffalo Wild Wings, Crazy Harry's Wild Steak House, and the like.

Comment: @JimHorn I regularly get matches for "[this is a great] opportunity" because I have a search-email-alert for "unity".

Answer (score 62):

Your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) say that you'd like to see jobs with a variety of tags, [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) included. Ads in the sidebar are driven by these settings and by the tags on your [previous question views](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) which has a high number of views for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). I suspect Unity questions are often tagged with C# which explains the high number of C# views you have.

[unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) has only 28 results across all 7,000 jobs on the board, 13 that are located in the US and 0 near where your current location is.

In short, this isn't a bug; we don't have any [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) jobs to show you and according to your settings and historical traffic we thought [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) jobs would be a good fit.

Comment: Thanks Dean, it's been a while since I set those preferences up and forgot how to find them.