# I don't want to work with a technology, yet I'm suggested jobs in it

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I have this setting in my profile. To name a few, I don't want to work with [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)

[image]

Yet I see these jobs [on this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab). Is it a bug?

[image]

When I asked the question a part of me thought  that it's due to the fact that I had just updated the *I prefer not to work with* field and that the setting needs some time to propagate to the job list (as is in some cases of some badges that are received as soon as a script runs and not always immediately) however, 24 hours have passed and I still see [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) jobs, on the first page.

Comment: Do you view a lot of questions with the other tags on those positions?  If so, this may be related?  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369875/want-a-c-job-no-actually/369901#369901 .

Comment: Interesting - but I only have 74 views in that technology as opposed to 1841 in JS, so I guess (or hope) it's not that

Comment: Have you considered going to some related conventions or joining online user communities of these technologies, to help you accept them? If S.O. and the job market feel that strongly that you should work with those technologies, it's probably a best practice to troubleshoot the lack of desire.

Comment: I don't blame you for not wanting to work with these technologies :)

Comment: Now I'm curious what "Remote - Paid relocation" means. Will they pay for a new chair at home?

Comment: It's kind of a hard question though. Let's say you don't want to work with React, but there's some company that works with both React and Vue. Working there wouldn't necessarily mean you have to do React...do you want to miss out?

Comment: @Hack-R Have you considered that sometimes people simply don't like certain technologies be it through lack of documentation, ill-fitting ecosystem, general principle or other personal motivations?

Comment: Haha I was mostly joking of course, but Steve Bennett's point is probably the *real* answer. I also really like pipe's observation. I want a paid relocation remote job!

Comment: @Hack-R I know... it sounds awesome. Can you pay to relocate me from Texas to Hawaii in order to work remotely from your Illinois office? :)